# SQL: earliest date from set of date fields

Tags: sql, mysql, datetime, date

I have a series of dates associated with a unique identifier in a table. For example:

```
1 | 1999-04-01 | 0000-00-00 | 0000-00-00 | 0000-00-00   | 2008-12-01 | 
2 | 1999-04-06 | 2000-04-01 | 0000-00-00 | 0000-00-00   | 2010-04-03 | 
3 | 1999-01-09 | 0000-00-00 | 0000-00-00 | 0000-00-00   | 2007-09-03 | 
4 | 1999-01-01 | 0000-00-00 | 1997-01-01 | 0000-00-00   | 2002-01-04 |
```

Is there a way, to select the earliest date from the predefined list of DATE fields using a straightforward SQL command?

So the expected output would be:

```
1 | 1999-04-01
2 | 1999-04-06
3 | 1998-01-09
4 | 1997-01-01
```

I am guessing this is not possible but I wanted to ask and make sure. My current solution in mind involves putting all the dates in a temporary table and then using that to get the MIN()

thanks

Edit: The problem with using LEAST() as stated is that the new behaviour is to return NULL if any of the columns in NULL. In a series of dates like the dataset in question, any date might be NULL. I would like to obtain the earliest actual date from the set of dates.

SOLUTION: Used a combination of LEAST() and IF() in order to filter out NULL dates.

```
 SELECT LEAST( IF(date1=0,NOW(),date1), IF(date2=0,NOW(),date2), [...] );
```

Lessons learnt a) COALESCE does not treat '0000-00-00' as a NULL date, b) LEAST will return '0000-00-00' as the smallest value - I would guess this is due to internal integer comparison(?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select id, least(date_col_a, date_col_b, date_col_c) from table
```

upd

```
select id, least (
  case when date_col_a = '0000-00-00' then  now() + interval 100 year else date_col_a end,
  case when date_col_b = '0000-00-00' then  now() + interval 100 year else date_col_b end) from table
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion - the problem with LEAST() is that it returns NULL dates (0000-00-00) as the minimum which I do not want ; I want the earliest actual date defined in any of those columns.

Comment: Thanks - I used a similar approach in the end combining IF's instead of CASE. SELECT LEAST( IF( date1 = 0, NOW(), date1), [...]). NULL dates can be compared with '= 0'.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can do it like bellow or using a large `case` structure... or with `least(date1, date2, dateN)` but with that null could be the minimum value...

```
select rowid, min(date) 
  from
       ( select rowid, date1 from table
         union all 
         select rowid, date2 from table
         union all 
         select rowid, date3 from table
         /* and so on */
       )
group by rowid;
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

```
select
  id,
  least(coalesce(date1, '9999-12-31'), ....)
from
  table
```

Comment: Good idea but '0000-00-00' is not considered a NULL value by COALESCE. For example, SELECT('0000-00-00', NOW()) will return 0000-00-00

Comment: Then it's not actually `null`.  Use `case` instead of `coalesce`.